# How to create an instance of a ViewController in the MainStoryboard file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm asked to create an instance of the DateChooserViewController in the MainStoryboard.storyboard file. I'm not sure where or how this is done.

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more detail than that.

Comment: Pull a ViewController in and set its class to `DateChooserViewController`. Since this is the most common task you do in storyboards you should probably read something about working with storyboards. Rays Tutorial is a pretty good start. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Depending of want you want to accomplish:

1. If you want to change the `type` of a the default view controller in `storyboard` you need to set the class of your view controller in the **`identity inspector`**. (I think that's what you want to accomplish)
2. If you want to instanciate a view controller through its **`identifier`** define in `stroryboard`, you can proceed this way in your code:

`DateChooserViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DateChooserViewController"];`

Comment: I'm getting familiar with Xcode UI can you please point me out where the identity inspector is? Thanks a lot for responding.

Comment: This is part of the utilities view on the right side of your workspace. You will see multiple sections on the top - choose the third from the left this is the identity inspector.